# How to plot a point with marker 'o' and specify size by Radius?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have tried plotting points by

```
for i in points:
   plt.plot(i[0], i[1], marker = 'o', markersize = size)
```

Is there a way to specify the `markersize` by Radius? For example, if i want to plot a circle with specific radius using the method above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would be the unit of the radius?

Comment: When you say `specific radius`, in which units would you like that to be? Data coordinates? Axis fractions? Fraction of display with? Pixels? As you have discovered, `markersize` is proportional to the axis such that if you zoom in, the markers stay the same size.

Answer (score 1):

You can add another number for your radius to each point in `points`:

```
points = [[1,2,10], [2,3,20], [4,2.5,30]]
for i in points:
    plt.plot(i[0], i[1], marker = 'o', markersize = i[2])
```

Another way that is more appropriate is using dictionaries:

```
circles = [
    {'r': 10, 'points': [1,2]},
    {'r': 20, 'points': [2,3]},
    {'r': 30, 'points': [4,2.5]}
]

for circle in circles:
    plt.plot(circle['points'][0], circle['points'][1], marker = 'o', markersize = circle['r'])
```

[image]

Comment: I misunderstood the question then. I'll edit the answer.